# Assigning values in a collection object to a named range

Tags: vba

I'm having difficulties assigned values from a collection object to a named range (let say 20 individual cells under 1 named range).

FYI the collection contains 20 values as well, obtained from a row in a table (but added individually using a loop).

```
Set Data = Range("ProjektInformationRange")


For Each Value1 In Data

    For h = 1 To Range("ProjektInformationRange").Count

         Value1 = myCol(h)


    Next h

Next Value1
```

Any suggestions?:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it would work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim Data As Range
    Set Data = Range("ProjektInformationRange")

    Dim myColAs New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        myCol.Add i
    Next i

    For i = 1 To myCol.Count
        Data.Cells(i, 1) = myCol(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

You loop through all the items in your collection and then paste them in your Range, because the collection will start on index 1 and your range will also start with the cell(1, 1) you can loop pretty easy.

Looping through the range would imply to "manually" increment your counter like this:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim Data As Range
    Set Data = Range("ProjektInformationRange")

    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        col.Add i
    Next i

    Dim C As Range
    i = 1
    For Each C In Data
        C = col(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much for the help as well as the thorough explanation. Much Appreciated!